# D3 selection variable reuse after append

Tags: variables, d3.js, append

this might sound totally noob but I am confused about:

```
var link1=container.append("g").selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
```

If I use link1 again, would it append another "g" and "line" instead of just choosing them?

Or do i have to do something like link.select....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link1 gets assigned to the results of the right hand side, not the right-hand-side as you've typed it.  So it'll point to the "line" that got created.

Comment: Does it mean: var link1=container.append("g") equal to link1=container.select("g") ?

Comment: Essentially, yes, that's the effective result.